# how to write a formula in c#?

Tags: formula

how to write a formula like

v_r (t)=∑_(n=0)^(N-1)▒〖A_r (L_2-L_1 ) e^j(ω_c t-4π/λ (R+υt+L_(1+L_2 )/2  cos⁡〖(θ)sin⁡(ω_r t+2πn/N)))〗 ┤)  sinc(4π/λ-L_(2-L_1 )/2  cos⁡(θ)  sin⁡(ω_r t+2πn/N))〗

in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the formula to something the compiler recognizes.

[image: The Formula]

To it's equivalent using the a combination of basic algebra and the Math class like so:

```
p = rho*R*T + (B_0*R*T-A_0-((C_0) / (T*T))+((E_0) / (Math.Pow(T, 4))))*rho*rho +
    (b*R*T-a-((d) / (T)))*Math.Pow(rho, 3) +
    alpha*(a+((d) / (t)))*Math.Pow(rho, 6) +
    ((c*Math.Pow(rho, 3)) / (T*T))*(1+gamma*rho*rho)*Math.Exp(-gamma*rho*rho);
```

Example taken from: [Converting Math Equations in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30615/Converting-math-equations-to-C)

Comment: I understand this is an old post but I am tying to achieve the same thing but the formula that I am coping from word is not being properly parsed. Would it be something to do with Version of word. I am using 2010 where in the article its using 2007. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you have to figure out what all those symbols *mean.* I see the sigma which usually indicates sum-of, with `∑_(n=0)^(N-1)` probably translating to:

```
 N-1
∑
 n=0
```

This generally means the sum of the following expression where `n` varies from `0` to `N-1`. So I gather you'd need a loop there.

The expression to be calculated within that loop consists of a lof of trigonometric-type functions involving `π`, `θ`, `sin` and `cos`, and the little known `sinc` which I assume is a typo :-)

The bottom line is that you need to *understand* the current expression before you can think about converting it to another form like a C# program. Short of knowing where it came from, or a little bit of context, we probably can't help you that much though there's always a possibility that we have a savant/genius here that will recognise that formula off the top of their head.